# variable portability in $.ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, csv, d3.js

I get that A in ajax is asynchronous. But I can't find an alternatives to what i'm trying to do.
I have a graph that I need to feed with a javascript array. This array is made from a csv import.
So I'm trying to make a function that return an array with the function recupCSV():

```
data = [];
objet function (data, objet) {
  var jour = data[3].split("/");
  var start = new Date(jour[2], jour[1], jour[0]);
  var dtS = new Date(start.getFullYear(), start.getMonth(), start.getDate());
  jour = data[4].split("/");
  var end = new Date(jour[2], jour[1], jour[0]);
  var dt = new Date(end.getFullYear(), end.getMonth(), end.getDate());
  var workItem = {id: data[0],name: data[1],lane: data[2],start: dtS,end: dt ,desc: data[5]};
  objet.push(workItem);
}

function recupCSV(data) {
  donnee = [];
  $.ajax({
    url: "http://www.example.com/csvfile.csv",
    aync: false,
    success: function (csvd) {
      csv_as_array = $.csv2Array(csvd);
      for(var i in csv_as_array )
      objet(csv_as_array[i],data);
    },
    dataType: "text",
    complete: function () {
    }
  });
  return data;
}
```

I can see many reasons why it doesn't work, but I can't see any that would.. ;)

Comment: Your code makes no sense. `objet` is a function and also an array? Is it? I can't tell.

Comment: You're using several time the same variables names, like `objet` (already said by @Andy), `data` (in global and local scope). You need to resolve these problems before trying to work with CSV files.

Answer (score 0):

Ok sorry for all this mess, here's the code that actualy works :

```
d3.csv("file.csv", function (error, data) { 
csvAsArray = data;
localStorage.setItem('anobjectwithnoname', JSON.stringify(csvAsArray));
});
```

then in some function :

```
var csv = localStorage.getItem('anobjectwithnoname');
var csvAsArray = JSON.parse(csv);
```

this way i got the object out of the asynchronous "trap" ;)
sorry again for the messy code. please don't be to harsh with try and fail type of learning